# Obtener registros con mayor valor en un campo de una tabla con MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero es una consulta que me arroje solo las tuplas que tengan el numero mayor en el campo **his_fk_idSeg**, he intentado con ***DISTINCT*** y ***UNION*** pero no he logrado hacerlo, es decir, como un ***MAX*** pero de todas las cedulas.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que esta tratando obtener registros grupados por *his_id_fkCol*, pero por cada *his_id_fkCol*, quiere la fila con el *his_fk_idSeg* maximo..

Primero, tiene que obtener el par de `(his_id_fkCol, maximum his_fk_idSeg)` en un subconsulta GROUP BY.
Luego, el resultado se debe JOIN con la tabla original.

```sql
select b.* from
(
    select his_id_fkCol, max(his_fk_idSeg) as his_fk_idSeg from LaTabla
    group by his_id_fkCol
) a
join LaTabla b
on a.his_id_fkCol = b.his_id_fkCol AND a.his_fk_idSeg = b.his_fk_idSeg
```